# CardView click event and focus at same time

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have one `CardView` with custom selector which include focus state to true

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cvColor"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:foreground="@drawable/card_color_size"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true" >
```

My need is when I click on card it should be clicked as well as focused too. so I did something like this.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolderCard1 viewHolder,
            final int position) {
        viewHolder.size.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.tvSize.setText(size.get(position).get("size"));
        viewHolder.size.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                posSize = position;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + posSize,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                viewHolder.size.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

now when I click once of the item of `RecycleView` it works fine, both `Toast` and focus happens same time.

But as soon as I click next item it just like on first click card perform click event and on second it gets focus.

anyone has idea what should I do?

Comment: 'But as soon as I click next item it just like on first click card perform click event and on second it gets focus' - what does this mean?

Comment: it mean when I click card it only get focus does not perform click even, but when I click again on same card, now it performs click event.   In short card does not perform click event on first click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this few days back do I am posting here my answer if any one faeces this problem.

`SparseBooleanArray` did the trick in my case.

First of all declare `SparseBooleanArray` in your Adapter Class. and Initialize it in your constructor of adapter class.

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> size;
public final SparseBooleanArray selectedItems;

public Size(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> title) {
    this.size = title;
    selectedItems = new SparseBooleanArray(size.size());
}
```

Now I use `setSelected` for focusing selected card. inside `onBindViewHolder` (or `getView` in case you are using `BaseAdapter`).

```
viewHolder.size.setSelected(selectedItems.get(position));
viewHolder.size.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        posSize = position;

        if (selectedItems.size() == 0) {
            selectedItems.put(position, true);
        } else if (selectedItems.size() > 0) {
            selectedItems.clear();
            selectedItems.put(position, true);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code.
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolderCard1 viewHolder,
         int position) {
    viewHolder.size.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    viewHolder.tvSize.setText(size.get(position).get("size"));
    viewHolder.size.setOnClickListener(new Listener(position, viewHolder.size));
}
class Listener implements OnClickListener {
    private int position;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private CardView cardview;

    Listener(int position,  CardView cardview) {
        this.position = position;
        this.imageView = imageView;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

     posSize = position;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + posSize,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           CardView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);  

    }
}
```